# Regex test and store result in javascript

Tags: javascript

In ruby, I often use something like this:

```
if "my string123" =~ /string(\d+)/
  puts "I got #{$1}"
end
```

How would I do something similar in javascript?  Currently, I've been doing this but it feels dirty.

```
m = "my string123".match(/string(\d+)/)
if (m)
  puts "I got " + m[1]
```

Perhaps I should just live with this, but thought I'd ask if there was a syntax subtelty I was missing.  Thanks!

Comment: No, that's correct. The ruby way should feel dirty because it adds a hidden/extra syntax that you must understand. The js way is purely functional.

Comment: It should be noted that if you want to get only the captured part without the full match then you can use a global match: `/regexp/g`. Then your match will be returned in `m[0]`.

Comment: If this is the first time you use `m`, it should probably have the `var` keyword: `var m = ...;`. Also, I don't think JavaScript has `puts`.

Comment: @slebetman - one problem with the `/g` flag: you'd get `"string123"`, not `"123`"`, you're forgetting about the group.

Comment: @Kobi: Eh, yes. I just realised that. I thought the behavior was the opposite of what it is.

Comment: thanks guys.  I guess what this is really kind-of asking is if there's an automatic match variable the js results are stored in like $1/etc in perl/ruby/etc.  And it seems not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't missing anything.
*If `m` is already defined*, you could do `if(m = "string".match(/regex/))`, but this is less clean anyway, and you cannot use that with `var`.

Comment: how important is the 'var' anyways?  I used to not use it and it seemed to work fine in all browsers? :)

Comment: @Kevin - Thanks. As for `var`, it could be *extremely* important: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+var

Comment: @Kevin You probably know what `var`, `let`, and `const` do at this point, given its been 12 years, but I think I'll tell others if they don't know. (note, var is not often used in modern Javascript). var is a keyword in JavaScript that is used to declare a variable in the current scope. While it is true that in JavaScript, you could declare a variable without using the var keyword, it is generally considered bad practice to do so. Let is another keyword, but prevents you from accessing a  variable outside the scope it was defined in (though you can access it in a child scope).

Comment: `const` is another way to declare variables, but you can't redefine a value, nor change it, however, you can mutate the value, for example in this scenario: 
`const myArray = [1,2,3]`. This throws an error: `myArray = [4,5,6]` But this works: `myArray.push(4)` Or `myArray.pop()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

*this is just for testing the appearance of the expression in the text:*

```
    var a = "my string123"; //or given as data..
    var b = /string(\d+)/;
    if (b.test(a)) alert("found some digits inside");
```

*this is for getting an array of matches:*

```
var str = "Watch out for the rock!".match(/r?or?/g);
```

*str then contains ["o","or","ro"]*